# Sequence converging fast to $u:=\int_0^1 \tan(x^2)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

> Is there a sequence converging fast to $$u:=\int_0^1 \tan(x^2)dx$$ ?

The only sequence I know is the antiderivate of the Mac-Laurin-series for $\tan(x^2)$. But the terms upto $x^{99}$ only give an accuracy of $\ 2\cdot 10^{-12}$. I am looking for a sequence converging faster to $u$.

Comment: There are plenty of nice, applicable approximations from the ODE side of things.  In particular, we're looking to $y(1)$ where $y$ satisfies
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan(x^2), \qquad y(0) = 0
$$
unfortunately, these tend not to give you a sequence of iterates in the usual way.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into different methods of [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration)

Comment: I wonder if you could use instead the the taylor series for $x \mapsto t \mapsto \tan(t)$ around $t_0 = \pi/4$, substitute $x^2$ for $t$, and antidifferentiate. Now when you plug in $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, the powers of $x-x_0$ in each case will be powers of a number less than 1, and might converge relatively fast.

Comment: I don't think Taylor series expansion is a wise way to evaluate the integral.  Tangent series is complicated and inefficient.  Simpson's rule is a good choice.

Comment: @NgChungTak But still too weak to calculate the integral upto, lets say, $10^5$ digits. This is the motivation of the question, calculating many digits of $u$

Comment: @Peter well, using a [Newton-Cotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas) rule of sufficiently high order should do the trick.   Or, perhaps some variant of [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) will be better.

Comment: Just an observation: changing the variable so: $$u=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{-2 \log \cos 1} ( \arctan \sqrt{e^t-1} )^{-1/2} dt$$ makes the integral look awkward, but gives the series which converges faster, the first term already gives 2 correct digits: $$\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{-2 \log \cos 1}  t^{-1/4} dt \approx 0.39 $$ and further terms are even better: $$\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{-2 \log \cos 1}  t^{-1/4} \left(1 + \frac{t}{24} +  \frac{t^2}{640} \right) dt \approx 0.3984 $$ Still not suitable for computing many digits of $u$ of course

Comment: Probably many of the standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration techniques will work well on the series you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Tanh-sinh quadrature using extended precision does the trick:

```
clang++ --std=c++1z -O3 -march=native -Wfatal-errors -I./include main.cpp -o main.x -pthread
Float:
t = 0.398414
Double:
t = 0.398414444597165
Long double:
t = 0.398414444597165236
Quad:
t = 0.398414444597165235865066382856357
50 base-2 digits:
t = 0.39841444459716523586506638285635748339831818223944
100 base-2 digits:
t = 0.3984144445971652358650663828563574833983181822394509583852026195262773554019963844432498215880916726
200 base-2 digits:
t = 0.3984144445971652358650663828563574833983181822394509583852026195262773554019963844432498215880916726384332639697976561640547798687260172938587339614334418611603878586871876794885401524314013497136849
400 base-2 digits:
t = 0.3984144445971652358650663828563574833983181822394509583852026195262773554019963844432498215880916726384332639697976561640547798687260172938587339614334418611603878586871876794885401524314013497136848994450029589206171362748228205506847313977510540961372792539096039773937729915768696529556515408214397831702242000635021974954899682789007215886731707650844051303182944982828364229080142453788781107099
800 base-2 digits:
t = 0.39841444459716523586506638285635748339831818223945095838520261952627735540199638444324982158809167263843326396979765616405477986872601729385873396143344186116038785868718767948854015243140134971368489944500295892061713627482282055068473139775105409613727925390960397739377299157686965295565154082143978317022420006350219749548996827890072158867317076508440513031829449828283642290801424537887811071021124182703254017298178958478967194655754404904913897242002843180409600943763105903054560577257139768624074611700805232801191202452708646002264841192848968716585768165750208421245067666380760437378349992731400909217102998220890841348008548840452050901204439293120312764842806429808136048929052403316765170095679577680678428326335714195595708642328167112225081595556536600545759572509329258822871525006
1600 base-2 digits
t = 0.3984144445971652358650663828563574833983181822394509583852026195262773554019963844432498215880916726384332639697976561640547798687260172938587339614334418611603878586871876794885401524314013497136848994450029589206171362748228205506847313977510540961372792539096039773937729915768696529556515408214397831702242000635021974954899682789007215886731707650844051303182944982828364229080142453788781107102112418270325401729817895847896719465575440490491389724200284318040960094376310590305456057725713976862407461170080523280119120245270864600226484119284896871658576816575020842124506766638076043737834999273140090921710299822089084134800854884045205090120443929312031276484280642980813604892905240331676517009567957768067842832633571419559570864232816711222508159555653660054575957250932925882287152501043236941659816310293244689289589896125917163537495015639496862935573373187078089110375318533392633685893118132175560728252839906025780671325299042259106521487443635379928758808283203917442957740259172503398324821292072534578859549893808380206428965498925092043238126997537341458184156744087233095221415417966255263405265119831441625604322429787212062765725312023801318841252149501931328700195413116144640356751305179299444924014867373898680030188909813047202630079710265773891101387871332058455879476773842694286524786642328837070632184003524621546810809039999050552177431177754256520435982867791995781647221480437625528649801230154688008431372525904773010771719232797172387862481275141452320529991534949133618071931488618356259446164147363231810514681711920911546649560213630406828802388979797882975
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/math/quadrature/tanh_sinh.hpp>

template<class Real>
void test_tan()
{
    using std::tan;
    using std::numeric_limits;
    using boost::math::quadrature::tanh_sinh;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<Real>::digits10);
    auto f = [](Real x)->Real { return tan(x*x); };

    tanh_sinh<Real> ts(400);
    Real t = ts.integrate(f, (Real) 0, (Real) 1);
    std::cout << "t = " << t << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Float:\n";
    test_tan<float>();
    std::cout << "Double:\n";
    test_tan<double>();
    std::cout << "Long double:\n";
    test_tan<long double>();
    std::cout << "Quad:\n";
    test_tan<cpp_bin_float_quad>();
    std::cout << "50 base-2 digits:\n";
    test_tan<cpp_bin_float_50>();
    std::cout << "100 base-2 digits:\n";
    test_tan<cpp_bin_float_100>();
    std::cout << "200 base-2 digits:\n";
    test_tan< boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float<200>>>();
    std::cout << "400 base-2 digits:\n";
    test_tan< boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float<400>>>();
    std::cout << "800 base-2 digits:\n";
    test_tan< boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float<800>>>();
    std::cout << "1600 base-2 digits:\n";
    test_tan< boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float<1600>>>();
}
```